# Negative timeout error in game loop

Tags: java

```
try {
            Thread.sleep( (long) ((lastTime - System.nanoTime() + ns) /1000000) );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above code seems to catch a negitive timeout value whenever I close out the program. How do I fix it?

Comment: Don't use Sleep for controlling framerate, Sleep is inappropriate for controlling framerate.

Comment: Yeah, sleep guarantees that it will sleep _at least_ the amount requested, not _exactly_ the amount requested. (Most likely it will sleep _longer_ than what you request.)

Answer (score 2):

If your last loop took longer than `ns` then your formula will give you a negative wait time since it fell behind schedule.

You have to check if the wait time is negative and skip waiting when that is the case.

Closing the program causes a lot of processing to happen during cleanup making that final loop take a very long time.